# scroll-behavior:smooth not working in tailwind

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using next.js and tailwind Css building my portfolio.
I already add scroll-behavior : smooth in globals.css file. And in Navbar, I used  to navigate to home page, and the rest of them I used id to navigate. However, I can only see the smooth effect when navigating to Home page, others not working. Could you please help me ? Thanks

[image][image]

I want to use scroll smooth effect in my page when navigating.

Comment: I've corrected your issue as well as giving you recommendations as of how you should treat the DOM with NextJS. Please, next time, also allow us to see your _app.js when DOM is involved, as it may also come down from that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from what does `<Link>`in Next.js.
By default, `<Link>` will go to the top, and then scroll back. You can read that from the [Link Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link), and that is totally expected: when you make the user go to another page, you don't want him to be at a random scroll position, but at the top of that new page. But here, we are staying on the same page, so we need to tell NextJS about that.

There is a way to prevent that behavior, by adding `scroll={false}` to it, which corrects your problem. But there are others issues as to how NextJS works and how you implemented that smooth behavior too. (From there, your initial problem is fixed tho)

So it'll looks like:
`<Link href="#link" scroll={false}>`

I'd suggest you to take usage of the `_document.js` file included in NextJS to manipulate `body` & `html` properties.

Here's my take on it according to your example:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html className="scroll-smooth">
      <Head />
      <body className="bg-[#ecf0f3] text-[#1f2937] tracking-wide ">
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

That way, you can clean down your CSS and have a native solution applied, you can be sure of that, to **every page** (as _document.js is the "template" of each page rendered in next)

You also should remove the "/" before your #id in the href as it deserves no purpose.

**Links that you can read from**

[_document.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document)

[Tailwind Smooth Scroll](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/scroll-behavior)

Comment: i was facing the same issue. this really helped fixed my problem, don't know the person asking the question fixed the problem or not but this is the accepted answer.
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can put scroll='false' inside the Link tag because that is how NextJS handles that.
For instance, according to your code,

> `<Link scroll={false} href='/#about'>  </Link>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).